# How to define a function that returns a list of all words in a file that are anagrams of a input string in python

Tags: python, string, function, python-3.3

I need to define a function called find_anagrams(str) which returns a lists of all words in dictionary.txt that are anagrams of the input string. I already have a code which returns words from a list that are anagrams of a string.

```
def find_anagrams_in_word_list(str1,str_list):
    anagrams = []
    for word in str_list:
        if len(word) == len(str1):
            if (anagram(str1,word)):
                anagrams.append(word)
                print(word)
```

and a code which opens the dictionary file

```
def get_dictionary_word_list():
    with open('dictionary.txt') as f:
        return f.read().split
```

How do i send the input string and the word list (get_dictionary_word_list) to find_anagrams_in_word_list to get the result?

so if the str was 'advar' i would like it to return 
'varad', 'davar', 'ravad' (assuming they are in the word file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in your previous question if `sorted(str1) ==  sorted(str2)` returns `True` you have an anagram. There is very little difference using a file, all you need is to split file into individual words, strip any whitespace and use a list comprehension again to compare:

```
def anagram(str1,str2):
    return sorted(str1) ==  sorted(str2)


def find_anagrams(s,f):
    with open(f) as f:
        return [word.rstrip() for word in f if anagram(word.rstrip(),s)]
```

Or using your own code:

```
def get_dictionary_word_list():
    with open('dictionary.txt') as f:
        return f.read().split() # need parens to call the split method

def anagram(str1,str2):
    return sorted(str1) ==  sorted(str2)


def find_anagrams(s):
    return [word for word in get_dictionary_word_list() if anagram(word,s)]
```

If you are using `split` you don't need `rstrip`

Comment: @padrraiccunningham using my own code this brings the error 'built in function object not iterable'.

Comment: You are missing parens to call the function `split()`,use the code in my answer

Comment: @padriaiccunningham Could you explain to me what parens are as i needed to make use of the get_dictionary_word_list() function

Comment: because `split` is a method of the str class, just like when you call `get_dictionary_word_list()` you need to add the parens to actually call the function, try `print(get_dictionary_word_list)`

Comment: if you use the three functions in the second half of my answer, that will work, I have commented beside where you missed adding the parens in your code it is `f.read().split` in mine it is `f.read().split()`

Answer (score 1):

I would make a function called `isAnagram` to check if a particular word itself is an anagram. The parameters can be the original word, and the word you are testing.

```
from collections import Counter
def isAnagram(original, test):
    return Counter(original) == Counter(test)
```

Testing this function:

```
>>> isAnagram('basket', 'skabet')
True
```

Now we can use the above function while reading (assuming one word per line in `dictionary.txt`). The parameters can be the path to the file, and the word you want to find anagrams of.

```
def getAnagramList(filename, original):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return [word for word in f if isAnagram(original, word)]
```

With a test file with a few anagrams of `'basket'`

```
>>> getAnagramList('dictionary.txt', 'basket')
['skabet', 'tebask', 'askbet']
```